# How would I add a title before the ul using wp_nav_menu?

Tags: wordpress, menu

I need to add a title to my menu, which is being built by wp_nav_menu...something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">My Menu Title</div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I find it strange that this isn't included by default :s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work for you!

```
wp_nav_menu(
  array(
    'items_wrap' => '<div class="title">Your menu title</div><ul class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>'
  )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a slightly broken option, I followed the guide on the wordpress codex, and a linked recommended guide, and every time, items_wrap did nothing at all, my original menu code was

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary','items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="sf-menu %2$s">%3$s</ul>' ) ); ?>
```

Which didn't work and after much hair pulling, I changed to this

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'items_wrap' => '<ul class="sf-menu %2$s">%3$s</ul>' ) ); ?>
```

Which does, both are basically identical, so if it doesn't work first time don't give up, strip back and keep trying!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WordPress function [`wp_get_nav_menu_name`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_name) to display the menu title where you want, based on the theme location.

For the primary menu for example, you can use :

```php
<h3><?php echo wp_get_nav_menu_name( 'primary' ); ?></h3>

<?php wp_nav_menu([
    'theme_location'  => 'primary',
    // ...
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Commonly there is a way to do it without editing core. I copied the wp_nav_menu() function codes and slightly modified to do it.

```
  // set menu arguments
  $args = array('theme_location' => 'primary_navigation');

  // if menu parameter set directly get menu object directly
  if (isset($args['menu']))
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $args['menu'] );
  // otherwise get it from theme location
  elseif ( !isset($menu) && $args['theme_location'] && ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ $args['theme_location'] ] ) )
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $args['theme_location'] ] );

  // if menu name exists, pass it into items_wrap
  if (isset($menu) && isset($menu->name))
    $args['items_wrap'] = '<h6>'. $menu->name .'</h6><ul class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>';
    wp_nav_menu($args);
```

According to [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/b/b3/donthack.jpg), you should never hack WordPress core, because:

[image: Do not hack core]

Answer (score -3):

Hack function wp_nav_menu() in /wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php
add after line 270

```
$nav_menu = $items = '';
```

this line:

```
$nav_menu .='<h3>'.$menu->name.'</h3>';
```